# different result when run code independently and code inside war

Tags: java, linux, shell

the following piece of code runs just fine if I put in java file in any folder (not run via war)

```
new ProcessBuilder("ssh b15h278@my.host.com \"echo success\"").start();
```

I got "success". but if I deploy the code as war, it will give me "Permission denied (publickey).". I've registered the key in target host.

Comment: When you run the code yourself, what userid are you running it as? When it runs in the WAR (and fails), what userid is it running as? Have you taken steps to make sure it uses the same key in both cases?

Answer (score 1):

To establish a working SSH connection, you need a public key on the system you are trying to log into and a private key on the local system.  By default, the "ssh" command will look for private keys in "$HOME/.ssh"

I suspect that the problem here is that when you run "ssh" from the webapp, you are actually running as a different user (e.g. "tomcat"), and that `$HOME` refers to a directory with no ".ssh" subdirectory.

Try giving the "ssh" an explicit "-i" parameter with the (absolute) path of the private key file.  Also, make sure that the file is readable by the "tomcat" user (or whatever it is).  (It is normal practice to set the permissions on your "$HOME/.ssh" directory so that other users / groups cannot read it.)